# Locking sqlite3 db for file download

Tags: c++, c, database, sqlite, locking

I have a sqlite3 database on some system which I need to download during ongoing operation. Stopping or pausing the accessing processes is not an option. So as far as I understand this I need to hold a SHARED lock (as described in http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) to the db during download to avoid db changes and corruption during download. How do I explicitly get such a lock? The download is controlled from a C++-program, so I would need to get the lock there.

EDIT: thkala suggested to make a db dump. But I would prefer to find a solution with locking because I'm not sure if there will be sufficient memory available for a complete copy of the db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, no. no and no!

Messing with locks and copying files by hand is the old way to do things. SQLite now has a proper [backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) that you can use. It is the recommended way to perform on-line copies of an SQLite database - you can use it to create a copy of the database, which can be then downloaded at your convenience.

EDIT:

If you absolutely *have* to use locking, you can use the method outlined [here](http://stuvel.eu/blog/55/safely-copy-a-sqlite-database) - possibly after translating into C:

- Open the database
- Use the [`BEGIN IMMEDIATE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) statement to acquire a shared lock.
- Copy/download the files manually - make sure that you don't miss any. There are at least the DB file, the journal file and possibly the WAL file. You might want to place the DB in a separate directory to make things simpler.
- [`ROLLBACK`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) the transaction you just started.

I understand how this method could be useful in some cases, but I have to repeat that this *is not* the recommended method any more.

Comment: Did not know about the backup API, very nice!

Comment: Using the backup API is a problem as I'm not sure if I have sufficient space available to make a full copy of the db.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of overlooked the solution:
Start a transaction with

```
BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSCTION
```

and end it with

```
END TRANSACTION
```

to aquire the lock. The `IMMEDIATE` keywords is not default and the db is already locked (RESERVED lock aquired) when the call returns.

Answer (score -3):

The solution here is wrong, leaving it for posterity and for people to learn why it's a bad idea.

<strike>I think you can also get away with copying the database along with the journal.(copy both db and journal to tmp files and then download them) Then on the remote end try to open this databse and it will fix itself. This is provided that the app is using proper transactions.</strike>

Please read below comments which explain why it's wrong:

> The gist of it is, you could copy the db & journal, but only if you
>   could get BOTH from EXACTLY the same instant in time.

Which is more or less impossible.

Comment: NO! NO! NO! This a *recipe* for data corruption! DB journals require proper filesystem semantics - which you DO NOT HAVE when copying files over a network. -1

Comment: Problem 1: Over the web, the DB file could be downloaded seconds or even *minutes* after/before the journal

Comment: I don't think this will work if there is write access during the copying.

Comment: But isn't the journal supposed to prevent data corruption? I explicitly said to copy the said files first so that seconds are out of the question.

Comment: Problem 2: It is quite possible that when you download the DB, the start of the file will be at transaction N, and by the time you finish, it's end will be at transaction N+M...

Comment: I agree that it is a totally not correct way to achieve this task but I would love to see a test whether it works. Imagine, upon power loss one file could already by synced and the other not. There must be something preventing the inconsistency.

Comment: @RushPL: Seconds are not out of the question. The db file may be of significant size and the file access will be slow (CF card). Also, gambling seems not appropriate here.

Comment: It is a bit of a gambling, isn't it? I wouldn't argue. Cheers.

Comment: To clarify: Yes, the journal prevents file corruption. But it does it because the journal and the db file are kept in lockstep (they are modified in a certain order). Read how SQLite implements atomic commit: http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html for more details. The gist of it is, you could copy the db & journal, but only if you could get BOTH from EXACTLY the same instant in time.